# How to have each tab name to have its own row on small screen?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, daisyui

I'm using daisyUI's [radio tab lifted + tab content](https://daisyui.com/components/tab/#radio-tab-lifted--tab-content). The code is the same with the demo, except the tab names are long:

```html
<div role="tablist" className="tabs tabs-lifted">
  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" className="tab" aria-label="Tab 1 is very long" />
  <div role="tabpanel" className="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6">Tab content 1</div>

  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" className="tab" aria-label="Tab 2 is very very long" checked />
  <div role="tabpanel" className="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6">Tab content 2</div>

  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" className="tab" aria-label="Tab 3 is very very very long" />
  <div role="tabpanel" className="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6">Tab content 3</div>
</div>
```

([Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/kuDMa8J3sD?layout=preview&size=198x720))

On small screen, the tab names are shrunk like this:

[image]

Is there a way to have each tab name to have its own row on small screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabs are organized using an implicit grid layout, whereby the tabs are displayed on the first row, with the content panels displayed on a second row.

We can the `grid-row`/`grid-column` classes along with `max-*` variant to reorganize the tabs to their own rows. The content panels should then occupy the next grid row with no tab in it.

I have had to use the `!important` modifier in the inline snippet due to using CDN and thus Tailwind's CSS comes before Daisy UI's CSS, but you may not need to use this modifier. I have used `max-md:` as the responsive breakpoint as an example.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/daisyui/4.6.1/full.min.css" integrity="sha512-GPsEpdPx4PTEpE1Aqx5JVCm4PZVRRZhZWLKUzsqxxO+fViF9wptiDbY3/oZpeNir5goDpThsweit2UVcMovogQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div role="tablist" class="tabs tabs-lifted">
  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 1 is very long" />
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6 max-md:!row-start-4">Tab content 1</div>

  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab max-md:!row-start-2 max-md:!col-start-1" aria-label="Tab 2 is very very long" checked />
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6 max-md:!row-start-4">Tab content 2</div>

  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab max-md:!row-start-3 max-md:!col-start-1" aria-label="Tab 3 is very very very long" />
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6 max-md:!row-start-4">Tab content 3</div>
</div>
```